# REST API architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, api-design

I just started to construct REST API refer to [this guide](https://restfulapi.net/).
It's my first time coustructing REST API architecture, so something ambiguous.

1. POST vs GET

Before learning about REST API, I choose POST when I don't want form-data being exposed(e.g. user's ID, password, phone number).
But in REST API, POST means '**create new resource**' if what I learn is right.
If so, what is the proper method for following case : 
'check user's ID is duplicate or not', 'find my id or password'

2. represent specific action

REST API guide says that use **noun** to represent.
I Usually named function or method by verb+noun combination(e,g, checkId, findPassword).
Then what is proper(or better) way to represent?

GET /user/check-id
GET /user/id/check
GET /user/id/duplicate

Comment: POST does not mean `create new resource`. POST means: perform some operation that will not be Idempotent or Safe. That's it. POST is often used to create new resources, but it is definitely not limited to that function.

Comment: thank for your kind comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look at the RESTful verbs](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).  POST is definitely used to create something, and GET is a query.  That being said, you are absolutely right that GET URL Parameters are often logged all over the place, and you should not use them in GET urls if they contain sensitive data.

To check if a user's ID is a duplicate, I'd do a POST with the user's ID, and return a HTTP 409 code if it already exists.

The find password is a different question.  In short, don't do it.  You should NEVER, EVER, EVER store a user's password in plain-text.  Doing so is negligence in today's computing world.   Resetting a password should involve creating a password reset request (A POST to a /user/id/reset), which results in a password request being sent via another channel, but never, ever return a password from a GET request.

Comment: Absolutely yes, password will reset and send to user's email when 'find a password'.  Many many thank you.